# Why TextView color change to blue when parsing it a string value from Html.fromHtml()

Tags: android, html, textview

I have a HTML string which is being fetch from server. I'm showing it in my textview like this:

```
detailText.setText(Html.fromHtml(offer.getDetailDesc()));
```

Now the activity in which this textview is place has black background and i have set my textview color to white in xml.
But when i set the text of textview, the color changes to blue. Why this is happening? Also, there are no links or color attributes in the html tags string and i just want to show the text in white.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like there is some kind of hyperlink in your html. To check it out, use this in your textview xml android:textColorLink="yourcolorhere" and set it to a different colour like pink. If the text is showing pink then you got the problem.

Comment: so i was wrong, there is one tag of font with color attribute in the html string, now my question is it possible to not apply that color from the font color attribute?

Comment: try android:autolink="none"

Comment: @Quark no sir there is no link in the html text, but a <font color="#0B333C'> which is making the whole text blue `<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="1"><B>1% rebate at over 19,500 brand-name participating gas stations nationwide</B></FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround:

1. Download your html text.
2. Use String class methods or Matcher Android Class to find patterns like this `<font color.*>` Remember to take the shortest match always.
3. Crop the String and pass it to the `HTML.fromHtml() method`
4. Apply to your textView.